# Windows Batch How to delete specific words from txt file

Tags: batch-file, for-loop, findstr

I can't figure out how to remove a piece of text in a line.

I have a batch file that creates a list of files of interest to me in the selected folder.

```
dir D:\pool\template_test>U:\Desktop\list.txt
findstr "Work_T" U:\Desktop\list.txt > U:\Desktop\tamplates.txt
```

Output:

```
2013-03-13  17:24               622 Work_T_tamplate1.fdf
```

In final file, as you can see, presents the date, time, size, but I only need the name. How can I do this?

I tried to use the example from the other post, but it does not work:

```
for /f "tokens=3" %%A in (U:\Desktop\tamplates.txt) do findstr /C".dot" /C".pdf" /C".fdf" %%A
```

[final file after using proposed code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RKDNL.png)

Comment: "It does not work" is not a quite precise failure description! Anyway, you missed the `:` behind `/C`, so it must be like `/C:".dot"`...

Comment: `cd /d "D:\pool\template_test"` and `dir /b *.dot *.pdf *.fdf`

Comment: I would suggest `dir /b "D:\pool\template_test" *.dot *.pdf *.fdf` which solves your problem.

Comment: so where exactly does the replace portion come in?

Comment: TBF, as the example provided 'from the other post' is not the question; the solution to the question asked is `Dir /B "D:\pool\template_test\*Work_T*">"U:\Desktop\tamplates.txt"`. Poligraf, this could easily have been solved had you read the help information for the `Dir` command you were using. _The easiest way to have achieved that is from the Command Prompt by entering `dir /?`_

Comment: @GerhardBarnard: it's `/b`, which removes date, time and size... `;)`

Comment: @Stephan, thanks yeah, I figured that part, but the heading is a little confusing :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you already got an answer in comments by [Stephan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2152082/stephan)

These will include the search for you, the following only returns the filename:

```
cd /d "D:\pool\template"    
(@for /f %%i in ('dir /b "Work_T*.dot" "Work_T*.pdf" "Work_T*.fdf" ') do (
    @echo "%%i"
  )
)>"U:\Desktop\tamplates.txt"
```

You could however also want the full path, so this would include the full path of the file:

```
cd /d "D:\pool\template"    
(@for /f %%i in ('dir /b "Work_T*.dot" "Work_T*.pdf" "Work_T*.fdf" ') do (
    @echo "%%~fi"
  )
)>"U:\Desktop\tamplates.txt"
```

add `/s` to recurse through subfolders if needed.

**Edit**

for UNC paths:

```
(@for /f %i in ('dir /b /a-d "\\tuesrna02\pool\template" ^| findstr /i "Work_T"') do (
    @echo %%i
  )
)>"U:\Desktop\tamplates.txt"
```

Comment: Wow, thanks a lot. And how to be in case of network drive: \\tuesrna02\pool\template ? In this case, cd /d does not work without mapping the disk ...

Comment: @Poligraf: no, `cd /d` doesn't work with network paths, but `pushd` does.

Comment: One more think – after using your code templates.txt contains
C:\Windows>() 
Work_T_HUB_confirm_PBSC_EN.dot

C:\Windows>() 
Work_T_TC_DFC_PBSC_EN.dot
Why does C: \ Windows> () appear here ?? And how to remove it?

Comment: Not sure I understand, can you post a screenshot of that in your original question please?